# How to use ViewModelProviders in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

I am new bie to Kotlin, Please help me how to use ViewModelProviders.of(this) in Kotlin

My code in java is

```
 mFavViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(FavouritesViewModel.class);
```

I am not able to find **ViewModelProviders** class in kotlin
tried auto convert but its showing errors.
Thanks.

Here is my DataModel class

```
class FavoritesDataViewModel:ViewModel{
    private var mFavHelper: DatabaseHelper
    private lateinit var mfav:ArrayList<Favorites>
     constructor(application: Application) {
        mFavHelper = DatabaseHelper(application)
    }
    fun getListFav():List<Favorites>{
        if (mfav==null){
            mfav =  arrayListOf<Favorites>()
            createDummyList()
            loadFav()
        }
        val clonedFavs = arrayListOf<Favorites>()
        for (i in 0 until mfav.size) {
            clonedFavs.add(Favorites(mfav.get(i)))
        }
        return clonedFavs
    }
    fun createDummyList(){
        addFav("https://www.journaldev.com", Date().getTime())
        addFav("https://www.medium.com", Date().getTime())
        addFav("https://www.reddit.com", Date().getTime())
        addFav("https://www.github.com", Date().getTime())
        addFav("https://www.hackerrank.com", Date().getTime())
        addFav("https://www.developers.android.com", Date().getTime())

    }
    fun addFav(url:String,date:Long):Favorites{
        val db:SQLiteDatabase = this.mFavHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        val values: ContentValues = ContentValues();
        values.put(DbSettings.DbEntry.COL_FAV_DATE,date)
        values.put(DbSettings.DbEntry.COL_FAV_URL,url)
        val id:Long = db.insertWithOnConflict(DbSettings.DbEntry.TABLE,
            null,
            values,SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE)
        db.close()
        val fav:Favorites = Favorites(id,url,date)
        mfav.add(fav)
        return Favorites(fav)
    }
    fun loadFav(){
        mfav.clear()
        val db:SQLiteDatabase = mFavHelper.readableDatabase
        val cursor:Cursor = db.query(DbSettings.DbEntry.TABLE,
             arrayOf(
                DbSettings.DbEntry._ID,
                DbSettings.DbEntry.COL_FAV_URL,
                DbSettings.DbEntry.COL_FAV_DATE
             ),
            null, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            val idxID:Int = cursor.getColumnIndex(DbSettings.DbEntry._ID)
            val idxURL:Int = cursor.getColumnIndex(DbSettings.DbEntry.COL_FAV_URL)
            val idxDate:Int = cursor.getColumnIndex(DbSettings.DbEntry.COL_FAV_DATE)
            mfav.add(Favorites(cursor.getLong(idxID),cursor.getString(idxURL),cursor.getLong(idxDate)))
        }
        cursor.close()
        db.close()
    }

}
```

tried with following line of code

```
var mFavViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity).get(FavouritesViewModel::class.java)
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
```

this is giving error:

```
  Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.nearex.mykotlinsample.viewmodel.FavoritesDataViewModel
            at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:153)
            at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:210)
            at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:134)
            at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:102)
            at com.nearex.mykotlinsample.view.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:29)
```

Comment: Please read official Kotlin naming style guide https://developer.android.com/kotlin/style-guide which says "***Special prefixes or suffixes, like those seen in the examples name_, `mName`, s_name, and kName, are not used*** except in the case of backing properties (which is prefixed by `_`)"

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Thanks for the suggestion. Will surely follow this.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**For Java**

For pre-AndroidX

```
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1'
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.0"
```

For AndroidX

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.2.0"
```

In the latest version, ViewModel can be declared as below

```
MyViewModel model = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel.class);
```

**For Kotlin**

For pre-AndroidX

```
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions-ktx:1.1.1'
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel-ktx:1.1.1"
```

For Android

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1"
```

ViewModel declaration

```
val model = ViewModelProvider(activity)[MyViewModel::class.java]
```

Refer below link for the latest [AndroidX dependency version](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#declaring_dependencies)

**Note**: For pre-AndroidX, the dependency version will not be updated

Comment: Just to expand this answer, make sure all your arch components dependencies are in the same format. That is: not mixing `android.arch` and `androidx` dependencies. Keep in mind that if you want to use the `Navigation Component`, at the moment of this coment it is only available as an `android.arch` dependency

Comment: @Mittal Varsani I have edited my question please check and help me

Comment: just make your constructor public and try @UmaAchanta

Answer (score 5):

Its assumed kotlin is in use - Class ViewModelProviders has been deprecated, instead ViewModelProvider can be used. To use this need to add a dependency in app build.gradle something like this -

```
 implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
```

Create a view model class -

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel(){
}
```

The same class object can be find from fragment - onCreateView. For example -

```
class MyFragment: Fragment(){
    ...
    private lateint var myViewModel: MyViewModel
    ...
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
         ...
         myViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
         ...

     }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Try with below

```
var mFavViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(activity).get(FavouritesViewModel::class.java)
```

Comment: getting error at ViewModelProviders. Its not importing

Comment: ViewModelProviders is now deprecated. You should use Mittal's answer in Kotlin.